# Facebook Access Token: MACHINE_ID

Tags: php, facebook, xmlhttprequest, facebook-access-token

I did a little PHP script that uses this principle: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension#long-via-code

Unfortunately when I send the `CODE` to the user and try to `HTTPrequest` (javascript), the page that should give me the `MACHINE_ID` responds with a random, changing string.

I guess `HTTPrequest` is called basically from the server, not the client. When I use direct URL connection I get the same string every time, but I cannot use the data, because it is just a web page, not a response.

Shouldn't the `MACHINE_ID` always be the same (for a certain device/browser session)?

Comment: _You_ have to make sure that you send the same machine_id as part of the request parameters, once you received one for the first time.

Comment: Thank you, I understand and have no problem with that, but imagine a scenario: I store the TOKEN and MACHINE_ID in my database and as a log-in session of the client, client logs-off destroying the session, then he logs-in from the same machine but I don't know which MACHINE_ID to use (my database has more records on that user, he logged-in from different machines ie). All I can do is call for a new one and it will be different.

Answer (score -2):

```
{
  "session_key": "5.xLL8XelWvN17yQ.1530200602.46-100004938759387",
  "uid": 100004938759387,
  "secret": "62818f28dadf1e5fdea17c70cc42b4e5",
  "access_token": "EAAAAUaZA8jlABAF8vs7Xp3bYhFrUjGZC7IJVIkBtsxGEbwjIhy7PtysyYCZB4ZBZAlXNvxSbsYZA9giZC8ZBhWZCpaTuYxGZBhGSo0sb1r5R8XPjmxbSHZCjuQgxjcgPlbVwsAVdboRHEyyc9cN6FfPFz3Jv9cB8xguVk4gyRCD6JQ5fhHBXxdykQwl",
  "machine_id": "GgI1W1EjtchM9UoB1IiILZke",
  "session_cookies": [{
    "name": "c_user",
    "value": "100004938759387",
    "expires": "Fri, 28 Jun 2019 15:43:22 GMT",
    "expires_timestamp": 1561736602,
    "domain": ".facebook.com",
    "path": "\/",
    "secure": true
  }, {
    "name": "xs",
    "value": "46:xLL8XelWvN17yQ:2:1530200602:15323:8134",
    "expires": "Fri, 28 Jun 2019 15:43:22 GMT",
    "expires_timestamp": 1561736602,
    "domain": ".facebook.com",
    "path": "\/",
    "secure": true,
    "httponly": true
  }, {
    "name": "fr",
    "value": "0LpS1kk8BIpMZ6ZnX.AWUXzwpmVcljO_CD31ozKSBgHno.BYGKXA.3G.AAA.0.0.BbNQIa.AWUgcG86",
    "expires": "Fri, 28 Jun 2019 15:43:22 GMT",
    "expires_timestamp": 1561736602,
    "domain": ".facebook.com",
    "path": "\/",
    "secure": true,
    "httponly": true
  }, {
    "name": "datr",
    "value": "GgI1W1EjtchM9UoB1IiILZke",
    "expires": "Sat, 27 Jun 2020 15:43:22 GMT",
    "expires_timestamp": 1593272602,
    "domain": ".facebook.com",
    "path": "\/",
    "secure": true,
    "httponly": true
  }],
  "confirmed": true,
  "identifier": "Christian.palele",
  "user_storage_key": "7086edcf13fb66e64be979ea719e8cd24d658ed3bce735e4f871dc69eda26409"
}
```